# Is there any way I can find out the required length of an input field using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Given this:

```
<input id="modalContentTitle"
  name="modalContentTitle"
  ng-minlength="5"
  ng-model="ahs.modal.data.title"
  ng-required="true" />
```

I know that I can access information on that field like this:

```
title="{{ ahs.vr5(ahs.forms.modal.modalContentTitle) }}"></i>

vr5 = function (field) {
    if (angular.isDefined(field)) {
        if (field.$error.required) return "Required";
        if (field.$error.minlength) return "Minimum 5 characters";
        if (field.$error.email) return "Email Invalid";
    }
    return "OK";
}
```

Is there a way that I can get the ng-minlength directly from the field information with AngularJS or do I need to create a different vr6 function if I want to verify lengths for fields with a minlength of 6.

Comment: you can do that using $attr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately minlength is a private variable within Angular.  You can however, do a workaround for this

```
<input id="modalContentTitle"
  name="modalContentTitle"
  ng-minlength="modalContentTitle.minlength = 5"
  ng-model="ahs.modal.data.title"
  ng-required="true" />
```

And now you can access this by

```
field.minlength
```